# Nagata-Smirnov Metrization Theorem for Pseudometric Spaces

Tags: general-topology, metrizability

The Nagata-Smirnov Metrization Theorem states that

> $X$ is metrizable iff it is $T_3$ and has a $\sigma$-locally finite base

So, I was wondering if this holds for pseudometric spaces too, if we remove the $T_0$ condition.

That is, is -

> $X$ is pseudometrizable iff it is regular and has a $\sigma$-locally finite base

true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is true and the result follows from the metric case. If $(X,d)$ is pseudometric, then there is the associated metric space (called the metric identification [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudometric_space)) has a $\sigma$-locally finite base and the corresponding base in $(X,d)$ is then as required, and conversely if we have a regular space with a $\sigma$-locally finite base, then its [Kolmogorov quotient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_space) is $T_3$ (from $T_0$ plus regular) and has a  $\sigma$-locally finite base too and so is metrisable and we pull back that metric to get a pseudometric on the original space.

Comment: Hi professor, could I ask your assistance [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3777796/if-b-subset-a-then-is-possible-that-partial-a-setminus-b-partial-a-cup-pa), please?