# If $\overline B\subseteq\overset{°}{A}$ then is possible that $\partial (A\setminus B)=\partial A\cup\partial B$?

Tags: general-topology

> **Lemma**
>
> If $X$ is a topological space then
> $$
> \partial(A\cap B)\subseteq[\overline{A}\cap\partial B]\cup[\partial A\cap\overline{B}]
> $$
> for any $A,B\subseteq X$.
>
> **Corollary**
>
> If $X$ is a topological space then
> $$
> \partial(A\setminus B)\subseteq\partial A\cup\partial B
> $$
> for any $A,B\subseteq X$.
>
> *Proof*. By the first lemma we know that
> $$
> \partial(A\setminus B)=\partial\big(A\cap(X\setminus B)\big)\subseteq[\overline A\cap\partial(X\setminus B)]\cup[\partial A\cap\overline{X\setminus B}]=[\overline A\cap\partial B]\cup[\partial A\cap\overline{X\setminus B}]\subseteq\partial A\cup\partial B.
> $$
> for any $A,B\subseteq X$.

So I ask if generally is $\partial (A\setminus B)=\partial A\cup\partial B$ when $B\subseteq A$ and if not I ask if with some additional hypotheses about $X$ (hausdorff separability, connectedness, etc...) or $A$ and $B$ it could be true. For example if the closure of B is contained in the interior of A then does the equality hold? So could someone help me, please?

Comment: Let $A=[0,1]^2$ and $B=[0,\frac{1}{2}]\times[0,1]$. Then...

Comment: @SangchulLee Okay, and if $A$ is open? could be it true?

Comment: You may tweak the above example in such case. On the other hand, if the closure of $B$ is contained in the interior of $A$, then the equality will hold.

Comment: @SangchulLee You said: «on the other hand, if the closure of B is contained in the interior of A, then the equality will hold». Could you prove this? I need it!

Comment: That follows from the formula on the last line. Then $\partial B \cap \overline{A}= \partial A$ and $\partial A \cap \overline{B}=\partial A$.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Umm... if $\overline B\subseteq\overset{°}A$ then $\partial B\subset\overline A$ so that surely $\partial B\cap\overline A=\partial B$ but I don't understand why $\partial B\cap\overline A=\partial A$. Then why $\partial A\cap\overline B=\partial A$? Could you explain, please?

Comment: Then by this why the statemet follows?

Comment: I meant $\partial A \cap \overline{X \setminus B} = \partial A$.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Excuse me, but I don't understand. Forgive my confusion.

Comment: If $A\subseteq B$ I know that $X\setminus B=A\setminus B\cup X\setminus A$ so that $\overline{X\setminus B}=\overline{A\setminus B}\cup\overline{X\setminus A}\subseteq\overline{A}\cup\overline{X\setminus A}$ and so $\partial A\cap \overline{X\setminus B}\subseteq\partial A\cap\Big(\overline{A}\cup\overline{X\setminus A}\Big)=\partial A$

Comment: The strict inclusion in $\partial(A\setminus B)\subseteq\partial A\cup\partial B$ occurs when the two boundaries $\partial A$ and $\partial B$ overlaps, hence some cancellation takes place in $A\setminus B$. But if we assume $\overline{B}\subseteq\mathring{A}$, then $\partial B\subseteq\overline{B}$ and $\partial{A}\subseteq X\setminus\mathring{A}$ are supported on disjoint closed sets, and so, we can prevent cancellation from happening and we may expect the equality to hold. I added the actual proof below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $B \subseteq A$. Then by using that $\overline{A_1\cup A_2} = \overline{A_1}\cup\overline{A_2}$ for any sets $A_1$ and $A_2$,

$$
\partial A\cup\partial B
\subseteq \overline{X\setminus A}\cup\overline{B}
= \overline{(X\setminus A)\cup B}
= \overline{X\setminus(A\setminus B)}. \tag{1} $$

Now we also assume that $\overline{B}\subseteq\mathring{A}$. Then

$$ \overline{X\setminus A} \cap \overline{B}
\subseteq \overline{X\setminus A} \cap \mathring{A}
= \varnothing. $$

So

\begin{align*}
\partial B
&= \overline{X\setminus B} \cap \overline{B} \\
&= (\overline{A\setminus B} \cup \overline{X\setminus A}) \cap \overline{B} \\
&= (\overline{A\setminus B} \cap \overline{B}) \cup (\overline{X\setminus A} \cap \overline{B}) \\
&= \overline{A\setminus B} \cap \overline{B}
\end{align*}

and this shows that $\partial B \subseteq \overline{A\setminus B}$. Simiarly,

\begin{align*}
\partial A
&= \overline{X\setminus A} \cap \overline{A} \\
&= \overline{X\setminus A} \cap (\overline{A \setminus B} \cup \overline{B}) \\
&= (\overline{X\setminus A} \cap \overline{A \setminus B}) \cup (\overline{X\setminus A} \cap \overline{B}) \\
&= \overline{X\setminus A} \cap \overline{A \setminus B}
\end{align*}

shows that $\partial A \subseteq \overline{A\setminus B}$. Consequently

$$ \partial A \cup \partial B \subseteq \overline{A\setminus B} \tag{2} $$

and combining $\text{(1)}$ and $\text{(2)}$ proves the inclusion $\partial A \cup \partial B \subseteq \partial (A\setminus B)$.

Comment: Okay, it is clear. However if $\overline{X\setminus A}\cap\overline B=\varnothing$ then why you write $(\overline{A\setminus B}\cap\overline{B})\cup(\overline{X\setminus A}\cap\overline{B}\subseteq\overline{A\setminus B}\cap\overline{B}$ and $(\overline{X\setminus A}\cap\overline{A\setminus B})\cup(\overline{X\setminus A}\cap\overline{B})\subseteq\overline{X\setminus A}\cap\overline{A\setminus B}$?

Comment: Why do not write and not $(\overline{A\setminus B}\cap\overline{B})\cup(\overline{X\setminus A}\cap\overline{B}=\overline{A\setminus B}\cap\overline{B}$ and $(\overline{X\setminus A}\cap\overline{A\setminus B})\cup(\overline{X\setminus A}\cap\overline{B})=\overline{X\setminus A}\cap\overline{A\setminus B}$?

Comment: Anyway thanks too much for your assistance!!!

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro, You are right. Originally I included the derivation $$\overline{X\setminus A} \cap \overline{B}
\subseteq \overline{X\setminus A} \cap \mathring{A}
= \varnothing$$ as part of the other two computations, and I forgot to replace $\subseteq$ by $=$ when I separated that part out. Now I changed those parts. :)

Comment: Don't worry, it can happen!

Comment: Hi, could I ask your assistance [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3790625/any-diffeomorphism-can-be-locally-factorised-with-several-primitive-diffeomorphi), please?