# Any diffeomorphism can be locally factorised with several primitive diffeomorphisms.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, solution-verification, alternative-proof, diffeomorphism

I ask in this question how to solve an exercise of the text *Analysis on Manifolds* by James Munkres: the exercise consist to prove a theorem about diffeomorphism with more restrictive conditions. Since the solution I gave is similar to the proof of the theorem that Munkres gave for sake of completenes I put it here but if you want you can directely read my solution and when I refer to Munkres's proof you can see the step I use because I indicate it explicitely

In text *Analysis on Manifolds* by James Munkres there is the following definition.

[image]

So Munkres states that any diffeomorphism can be locally factorised with several primitive diffeomorphims so that he claims that the following theorem holds.

[image]

Well Munkres prove it in four sep.

So in the first step he proves that any linear transfomation is a diffeomorphism that could be factorised locally with severl primitive diffeomorphisms as you can check (if you like) to follow.

[image]

Then in the second step he proves that any traslation is a diffeomorphism that could be factorised locally with two primitive diffeomorphisms as you can check (if you like) to follow.

[image]

Then in the third step he proves that the theorem holds in the case where $g(0)=0$ and $Dg(0)=I_n$ as you can check (if you like) to follow.

[image]

Finally in the four step he proves the general case using the preceding results.

[image]

However then as exercise Munkres ask to show that the preceding theorem holds with more restrictive definition of diffeomorphism that is he ask to prove the following statement.

[image]

So unfortunately I don't be able to use the Munkres's hit (are you able to do it?) but it seems I found the following alternative solution.

> - First of all we observe that any linear transmormation could be factorised with serveral primitive diffeomorphisms: indeed as you can check the elementary row operation of type $2$ and $3$ (for datail see the step $1$ of the preceding theorem) modify only the $i$-th row of a matirx and the elements of the $i$-th row of a matrix are the $i$-th components of the image of the vector of a base.
> - Then if $t$ is a traslation of length and direction $\pmb c:=(c_1,...,c_n)$ then for any $i=1,...,n$ we can define the primitive diffeomorphism
>   $$
>   t_i(x):=(x_1,..,x_i+c_i,...,x_n)
>   $$
>   and observe that
>   $$
>   t(x)=x+c_1\cdot e_1+c_2\cdot e_2+...+c_n\cdot e_n=
>   \\
>   =\Biggl(\Big(...\big((x+c_1\cdot e_1)+c_2\cdot e_2\big)+...\Big)+c_n\cdot e_n\Biggl)=\Biggl(\Big(...\big(t_1(x)+c_2\cdot e_2\big)+...\Big)+c_n\cdot e_n\Biggl)=\Biggl(\Big(...\big(t_2(t_1(x))\big)+...\Big)+c_n\cdot e_n\Biggl)=
>   \\
>   =...=t_n\Big(...\big(t_2(t_1(x)\big)...\Big)=(t_n\,\circ...\circ\,t_1)(x)
>   $$
>   so that any traslation could be factorised with serveral primitive diffeomorphisms.
> - Now as Munkres did we consider the special case where $a=0$, $g(0)=0$ and $Dg(0)=I_n$. So first we define the function $h_1A\rightarrow\Bbb R^n$ through the condition
>   $$
>   h_1(x):=\big(g_1(x),x_2,...,x_n\big)
>   $$
>   and we observe that if $g_1(0)=0$ and $Dg_1=e_1$ then $h_1(0)=0$ and $Dh_1(0)=I_n$ and so it follows form the inverse function theorem that $h_1$ is a diffeomorphism (**clearly it is primitive!**) of a open neighborhood $V_0$ of $0$ with an open set $V_1$ that contains $h_1(0)=0$. So now we define the function $h_2:V_1\rightarrow\Bbb R^n$ through the condition
>   $$
>   h_2(y):=\Big(y_1,\big(g_2\,\circ\,h_1^{-1}\big)(y),y_2,...,y_n\Big)
>   $$
>   for any $y\in V_1$ and we observe that if $g_2(0)=0$ and $Dg_2(0)=e_2$ then $g\big(h^{-1}_1(0)\big)=0$ and $Dg_2\big(h^{-1}_1(0)\big)=Dg_2\big(h^{-1}_1(0)\big)\cdot Dh^{-1}_1(0)=Dg_2(0)\cdot\big(Dh_1(0)\big)^{-1}=e_2\cdot I_n=e_2$ and so $h_2(0)=0$ and $D h_2(0)=I_n$ thus it follows form the inverse function theorem that $h_2$ is a diffeomorphism (**clearly it is primitive!**) of a open neighborhood $U_1$ of $0$ with an open set $U_2$ that contains $h_2(0)=0$. So the sets
>   $$
>   W_0:=h^{-1}_1[U_1\cap V_1], W_1:=(U_1\cap V_1)\,\,\,\text{and}\,\,\,W_2:=h_2[U_1\cap V_1]
>   $$
>   are open neighborhoods of $0$ and the function $(h_2|_{W_1}\,\circ\,h_1|_{W_0})$ is a diffeomorphism from $W_0$ to $W_2$ such that
>   $$
>   (h_2|_{W_1}\,\circ\,h_1|_{W_0})(x):=h_2(h_1(x))=h_2\big((g_1(x),x_2,...,x_n)\big)=\Big(g_1(x),\big(g_2\,\circ\,h^{-1}_1\big)\big((g_1(x),x_2,...,x_n)\big),x_3,...,x_n\Big)=\Big(g_1(x),\big(g_2\,\circ\,h^{-1}_1\big)\big(h_1(x))\big),x_3,...,x_n\Big)=\Big(g_1(x),g_2\big(h^{-1}_1(h_1(x))\big),x_3,...,x_n\Big)=\big(g_1(x),g_2(x),x_3,...,x_n\big)
>   $$
>   for any $x\in W_0$. So for $i<n$ we assume that $V_0,V_2,...,V_i$ is a collection of open neighborhoods of $0$ for which exist a sequence of primitive diffeomorphisms $h_1,...,h_i$ there defined such that
>   $$
>   h_1(0)=h_2(0)=...=h_i(0)=0\,\,\,\text{and}\,\,\,Dh_1(0)=Dh_2(0)=...=Dh_i(0)=I_n
>   $$
>   and moreover we suppose that
>   $$
>   \big(h_i\,\circ...\circ\,h_2\,\circ\,h_1\big)(x)=\big(g_1(x),g_2(x),...,g_i(x),x_{i+1},...,x_n\big)
>   $$
>   for any $x\in V_0$. So we define the function $h_{i+1}:V_i\rightarrow\Bbb R^n$ through the condition
>   $$
>   h_{i+1}(y):=\Big(y_1,...,y_i,\big(g_{i+1}\,\circ\,h_1^{-1}\,\circ\,h_2^{-1}\,\circ...\circ\,h_i^{-1}\big)(y),y_{i+2},...,y_n\Big)
>   $$
>   for any $y\in V_i$ and so we observe that if by assumption $g_{i+1}(0)=0$, $Dg_{i+1}(0)=e_{i+1}$ and if by the inductive hypothesis $h_1^{-1}(0)=h_2^{-1}(0)=...=h_i^{-1}(0)=0$ and $\big(Dh_1(0)\big)^{-1}=\big(Dh_2(0)\big)^{-1}=...=\big(Dh_i(0)\big)^{-1}=I_n$ then $$
>   (g_{i+1}\,\circ\,h_1^{-1}\,\circ\,h_2^{-1}\,\circ...\circ\,h_i^{-1}\big)(0)=0
>   $$
>   and
>   $$
>   D\big(g_{i+1}\,\circ\,h_1^{-1}\,\circ\,h_2^{-1}\,\circ...\circ\,h_i^{-1}\big)(0)=Dg_{i+1}(0)\cdot Dh_1^{-1}(0)\cdot Dh_2^{-1}(0)\cdot...\cdot Dh_i^{-1}(0)=e_{i+1}\cdot I_n\cdot I_n\cdot...\cdot I_n=e_{i+1}
>   $$
>   so that $h_{i+1}(0)=0$ and $Dh_{i+1}(0)=I_n$ and so it follows form the inverse function theorem that $h_{i+1}$ is a diffeomorphism (**clearly it is primitive!**) of a open neighborhood $
>   U_i$ of $0$ with an open set $U_{i+1}$ that contains $h_{i+1}(0)=0$. So the sets $$
>   W_0:=h^{-1}_1\Big[h^{-1}_2\big[...[h^{-1}_i[U_i\cap V_i]...\big]\Big],\,W_1:=h^{-1}_2\big[...[h^{-1}_i[U_i\cap V_i]...\big],\,...,
>   \\
>   W_{i-1}:=h^{-1}_i[U_i\cap V_i],\,W_i:=U_i\cap V_i\,\,\,\text{and}\,\,\,W_{i+1}:=h_{i+1}[U_i\cap V_i]
>   $$
>   are open neighborhoods of $0$ and the function $(h_{i+1}|_{W_i}\,\circ\,h_i|_{W_{i-1}}\,\circ\,...\circ\,h_2|_{W_1}\,\circ\,h_1|_{W_0})$ is a diffeomorphism of $W_0$ in $W_{i+1}$ such that
>   $$
>   \big(h_{i+1}|_{W_i}\,\circ\,h_i|_{W_{i-1}}\,\circ\,...\circ\,h_2|_{W_1}\,\circ\,h_1|_{W_0}\big)(x)=\big(h_{i+1}\,\circ\,h_i\,\circ\,...\circ\,h_2\,\circ\,h_1\big)(x)=\Big(h_{i+1}\,\circ\big(h_i\,\circ\,...\circ\,h_2\,\circ\,h_1\big)\Big)(x)=h_{i+1}\Big(\big(h_i\,\circ\,...\circ\,h_2\,\circ\,h_1\big)(x)\Big)=h_{i+1}\Big(\big(g_1(x),g_2(x),...,g_i(x),x_{i+1},...,x_n\big)\Big)=
>   \\
>   =\Biggl(g_1(x),g_2(x),...,g_i(x),\Big(g_{i+1}\,\circ\,h_1^{-1}\,\circ\,h_2^{-1}\,\circ...\circ\,h_i^{-1}\Big)\Big(\big(g_1(x),g_2(x),...,g_i(x),x_{i+1},...,x_n\big)\Big),x_{i+2},...,x_n\Biggl)=\Biggl(g_1(x),g_2(x),...,g_i(x),\Big(g_{i+1}\,\circ\,h_1^{-1}\,\circ\,h_2^{-1}\,\circ...\circ\,h_i^{-1}\Big)\Big(\big(h_i\,\circ...\circ\,h_2\,\circ\,h_1\big)(x)\Big),x_{i+2},...,x_n\Biggl)=
>   \\
>   =\Biggl(g_1(x),g_2(x),...,g_i(x),\Big(g_{i+1}\,\circ\big(h_1^{-1}\,\circ\,h_2^{-1}\,\circ...\circ\,h_i^{-1}\big)\Big)\Big(\big(h_i\,\circ...\circ\,h_2\,\circ\,h_1\big)(x)\Big),x_{i+2},...,x_n\Biggl)=
>   \\
>   =\Biggl(g_1(x),g_2(x),...,g_i(x),g_{i+1}\biggl(\Big(h_1^{-1}\,\circ\,h_2^{-1}\,\circ...\circ\,h_i^{-1}\Big)\Big(\big(h_i\,\circ...\circ\,h_2\,\circ\,h_1\big)(x)\Big)\biggl),x_{i+2},...,x_n\Biggl)=
>   \\
>   =\Biggl(g_1(x),g_2(x),...,g_i(x),g_{i+1}\biggl(\Big(\big(h_1^{-1}\,\circ\,h_2^{-1}\,\circ...\circ\,h_i^{-1}\big)\circ\big(h_i\,\circ...\circ\,h_2\,\circ\,h_1\big)\Big)(x)\biggl),x_{i+2},...,x_n\Biggl)=
>   \\
>   =\Big(g_1(x),g_2(x),...,g_i(x),g_{i+1}(x),x_{i+2},...,x_n\Big)
>   $$
>   for any $x\in W_0$. So finally by finite induction theorem we conclude that there exist a sequence $V_0,V_1,...,V_{n-1}$ of length $n$ for which exist a sequence $h_1,...,h_n$ of primitive diffeomorphism there defined,combinable and such that $g|_{V_0}\equiv h_n\,\circ...\circ\,h_2\,\circ\,h_1$.
> - Finally with the same arguments that Munkres did in the step $4$ we conclude that the theorem holds.

So I ask if the solution I gave to exercise is correct and if not I ask to solve it. So could someone help me, please?

Comment: The general proof you write is correct, but I did not check all the details. The proof suggested by the hint works in a very similar fashion just "in the other direction", ie while you iteratively add primitives diffeomorphisms to get from the identity to $g$, the proof suggested by the hint is to iteratively add primitive diffeomorphisms to undo $g$, ie to go from $g$ to the identity one component at a time.