# Can we construct a non-measurable set using only the axiom of countable choice?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, axiom-of-choice

I know that it's established that non-measurable sets cannot be constructed without the axiom of choice but I was wondering if countable choice was enough? Since the ones that I have seen use uncountable choice.

My intuition tells me no. Since I tend to think of measurable sets as being closed under "countable operations". Although if we're being precise the operations in question are unions, intersections and complements; so i was wondering if we can use countable choice in some way to construct a non-measurable set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Countable choice is not enough. See Solovay example here  [https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-measurable_set#:~:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20a%20non-measurable,assigned%20a%20meaningful%20"volume".&text=Solovay%20constructed%20Solovay's%20model%2C%20which,of%20the%20reals%20are%20meas](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-measurable_set#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20a%20non-measurable,assigned%20a%20meaningful%20%22volume%22.&text=Solovay%20constructed%20Solovay%27s%20model%2C%20which,of%20the%20reals%20are%20meas)

Answer (score 1):

The axiom of countable choice is strictly weaker than the axiom of [dependent choice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_dependent_choice#Relation_with_other_axioms), which is not strong enough to prove the existence of non-measurable sets. However, with dependent choice and $\aleph_1\le 2^{\aleph_0}$ you [do get a non-measurable set](https://books.google.com/books?id=JXIiGGmq4ZAC&pg=PA122#v=onepage&q&f=false). The axiom of choice for pairs is also sufficient.

Comment: Hi professor, to solve [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3790625/any-diffeomorphism-can-be-locally-factorised-with-several-primitive-diffeomorphi) my question I tried to use the finite induction but unfortunately I suspect either that it is not possible to apply it or that I did it wrongly so could I ask for your assistance please?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro: I’m sorry, but I’m afraid that I’m the wrong person to ask about diffeomorphisms: that’s an area that I’ve never studied at all.

Comment: Okay, don't worry. I'm sorry for the trouble.

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro: No trouble!

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to construct a non-measurable set using only countable choice.  Solovay showed that (assuming the existence of an inaccessible cardinal) it is consistent to have $ZF+DC+$every set of reals is Lebesgue measurable.  Here $DC$ is dependent choice, which is strictly stronger than countable choice.

It's worth mentioning that Shelah has shown that the inaccessible cardinal is essential for getting Solovay's result.